# Get pixels associated with specific body part

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using the Kinect-SDK to track a person. However, the Kinect-SDK is only giving me information about the joints. I would like to get every pixel that is associated with a specific body part or joint.

For example, I want only my hand, foot, or whatever limb to be visible and the rest of the image should be removed. However, I did not find a way to associate a pixel with a specific part of the persons body. The only thing I found was that a depth pixel can be associated with a player but does it get any more specific?

I know that the SDK is labeling the body parts of a tracked person in order to compute the skeleton, but is this information still accessible somehow?
http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=145347

Comment: Have a look at the CoordinateMapper - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663707.aspx.  I can look at a more detailed answer when I'm at my computer.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey afaik with the CoordinateMapper I could only map the position of a joint into the color/depth space. However, this does give me only one point but no hint on which pixel is related to which joint. Mapping a color/depth pixel into skeleton space doesn't help either since again e.g. the hand-joint would be exactly one point but not a whole area in skeleton space.

Comment: Indeed, I had missed that point of the question.  As @MentohlBonbon mentions, there is no official SDK way to pull that information out.  You might be able to use a combination of `CoordinateMapper` and OpenCV's `findContours` to pull limbs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an opensource library that you can use for skeleton-tracking. Its called NITE. Find it here: http://www.openni.org/files/nite/#.UX7UT8rOj2k

You can also track hands with this.

In general: The RGB image and the depth image of the kinect map. So you can find out about the position of a hand in the depth image and then draw a circle at that position in the rgb image. Works great with e.g. openCV.

If you have more questions just ask, and please be specific.

**EDIT :**

You get the z-coordinate of the hand. 
You can use this as a reference and then you can threshold in the area of the hand(everything that is too far in terms of x or y cannot belong to the hand).

With OpenCV and it's function findContours you could find the area of the hand in the image and then color that area in another image the way you want it.

Comment: I'm afraid you will probably need to implement this yourself in a way.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear enough, so I tried to rephrase the initial question. I know, that there are libraries that can do skeleton-tracking and I'm using the Kinect-SDK to do this. My question is, if I can use the Kinect-SDK to get information wheter a pixel, in the image that I get from the Kinect, is assigned to a specific joint of a tracked persons skeleton?

Comment: The KinectSDK does, as far as I know, not support any functions that associate pixels in either the depth or the rgb image with certion joints or body parts. You willhave to write that code yourself.

Comment: The official Kinect SDK has several functions to associate pixels. Etween the different streams, including the `Skeleton`.  I'm not in front of my Kinect machine, so I'll have to look up specifics later.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey all the images map. So you can tell that at a certain position will be e.g. the Hand. But as far as I know there is nothing that will tell you: all these pixels belong to the hand.

Comment: Ah, I see the distinction.  I missed that detail before.  Apologies.

Comment: Is there maybe another library that could do this? Like OpenNI or something?

Comment: I don't think so. OpenNI works basically the same. If you don't know how to extract only one of your hands from the image, I think this will help: https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=kinect+hand+tracking&oq=kinect+hand+tracking&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i30l3.19062.24028.0.24524.20.12.0.8.8.0.73.577.12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.8mBuxEfZg-w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45921128,d.ZWU&fp=67cb823efbe14c69&biw=1920&bih=944